# Firebase custom token error - issuedAt is being generated 4 mins ahead

Tags: spring-boot, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a Spring Boot authentication server running on a EC2 on AWS us-east-2 region which generates Firebase custom authentication token for a Flutter mobile app.

Everything is working fine, except by the fact that Firebase token `issuedAt` variables are being generated 4 or 5 minutes ahead of Firebase default time. This makes the `FirebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken` return an error with `The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation` message.

I haven't found any option to set time in Java Firebase API and I can't change it's value after the token have been signed.

I've seen some other questions facing a similar problem, but I couldn't figure out a way to fix it.

**Edit 1**

On the server side, I generate the token this way:

```java
 return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(authService.getEmail());
```

And it really is a valid token, because if await 4 or 5 minutes before using it, it works. Otherwise, if I try to use it immediately, it doesn't.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the token verification that Firebase itself uses typically allows some leniency on when the token was created. Can you show how you generate and verify the token?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the comment, I've edited the question. Please, check it out.

Comment: Thanks for that update. At first glance that code looks fine indeed. It might be worth [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank van Puffelen suggested, I contacted Firebase Support and they told me to try to generate Firebase Token manually. So I did that, set `issuedAt` attribute to 10 minutes before and it worked properly.